# How to separate date only into separate column from single string via VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I need to separate date from the single column into another separate column as showed into output

Table

```
+--------------------------+
|           List           |
+--------------------------+
| Houston 05 01 2020       |
| Dallas 01 02 2020        |
| Austin 05 01 2020        |
| Addison 02 02 2020       |
| The woodlands 03 01 2020 |
| Sugar Land 01 01 2020    |
| Galveston 04 01 2020     |
| San Antonio 01 01 2020   |
| Arlinton 02 01 2020      |
| Irving 04 01 2020        |
| Plano 03 01 2020         |
| Euless 01 01 2020        |
+--------------------------+
```

Output: This is what i need into my output after I ran vba code

```
+----------------+-------------+
|      List      |             |
+----------------+-------------+
| Houston        | 05 01 2020  |
| Dallas         | 01 02 2020  |
| Austin         | 05 01 2020  |
| Addison        | 02 02 2020  |
| The woodlands  | 03 01 2020  |
| Sugar Land     | 01 01 2020  |
| Galveston      | 04 01 2020  |
| San Antonio    | 01 01 2020  |
| Arlinton       | 02 01 2020 |
| Irving         | 04 01 2020  |
| Plano          | 03 01 2020  |
| Euless         | 01 01 2020  |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: "I need" is not a question. Please read [ask] and show us what code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some VBA code that loops all data in column 1, loads it into an array split on spaces. It then outputs the last 3 elements of the array out as the date part, and builds up the previous elements into a space separated string before writing this out to the worksheet:

```
Sub sSplitDate()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim aData() As String
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lngLast = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngLoop1 = 1 To lngLast
        aData() = Split(ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 1), " ")
        strOutput = ""
        For lngLoop2 = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData) - 3
            strOutput = strOutput & aData(lngLoop2) & " "
        Next lngLoop2
        ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 2) = strOutput
        ws.Cells(lngLoop1, 3) = aData(UBound(aData) - 2) & " " & aData(UBound(aData) - 1) & " " & aData(UBound(aData))
    Next lngLoop1
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sSplitDate", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks Applecore :)